# Converting a decimal data type value to a formatted string

Tags: c#, sql-server, type-conversion

I want to convert the results of `Label22.Text` and `Label21.Text` to a number with two decimal places. Have tried a number of variations

```
sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT fname, SUM([debit]/1.2) AS [D], SUM([credit]/1.2) AS [C] FROM detail GROUP BY fname", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);
DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Select("fname = '0092632'").FirstOrDefault();

if (dr != null)
{
    Label22.Text = dr["D"].ToString();
    Label21.Text = dr["C"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: currently what you are getting ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to decimal with format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963317/convert-string-to-decimal-with-format)

Comment: Convert.ToDecimal() ?

Comment: Long numbers up to 5 decimal places such as 1009.65891

Comment: To Vishal. I'am getting Long numbers up to 5 decimal places such as 1009.65891

Comment: Avsenev Slava  - tried that, doesn't work

Comment: Blas Soriano - also tried that and doesn't work either

Comment: The solutions listed **do work**. You'll need to provide useful information if there is a reason they do not work for you, because the likelihood is, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Label22.Text = string.Format("{0:N2}", Convert.ToDecimal(dr["D"].ToString()));
Label21.Text = string.Format("{0:N2}", Convert.ToDecimal(dr["C"].ToString()));
```

Also try this

```
Label22.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", dr["D"].ToString());
Label21.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", dr["C"].ToString());
```

Comment: Hi Pravin. Afraid it did not work. tried fiddling around with it, but no joy

Comment: what is the output you are getting ? debug and watch

Comment: Willingly, but where do I do that ?  Is there a special button I need to press. As you have gathered, quite new to this

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in your query:

```
SELECT 
    fname, 
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,2), SUM([debit]/1.2)) AS [D], 
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,2), SUM([credit]/1.2)) AS [C] 
FROM 
    detail 
GROUP BY 
    fname
```

Comment: I like this one. Didn't know you can do it inside a query.

Comment: @callasda This is inside a query ;).