# C++ .net float to System::String^

Tags: mysql, .net, c++-cli

Hi I discovered when I access a float value from mySQL database and convert it to System::String^ then it change for example `3.15` to `3,15` but I want it to output `3.15` how do I do that. This is the code:

```
DataGridViewRow^ row = gcnew DataGridViewRow();
row->CreateCells(this->dataGridView1);
row->Cells[3]->Value = myReader->GetFloat(3);
this->dataGridView1->Rows->Add(row);
```

I have also tested:
`row->Cells[5]->Value = ("%f",myReader->GetFloat(5));` but it still give me a number with a comma for the decimal separator but I want a dot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to decimal with format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963317/convert-string-to-decimal-with-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
using namespace System::Globalization;

row->Cells[3]->Value = myReader->GetFloat(3).ToString(CultureInfo::InvariantCulture);
```